# Line Height in SSRS

Tags: css, reporting-services

Is there a way to adjust the line height in SSRS? I have a requirement on a legal document to have a bigger line height.

From what I have read, the `Textbox.LineHeight` property only affects html. I have converted the text inside the textbox to html, set the LineHeight property, but nothing changed.

I also tried adding custom CSS to the report (using old school `line-height: {x} pt;` inside a style tag), but to no avail - that isn't supported in the SSRS environment.

Here is an example what I need - How can I achieve this?

Before:

[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

Does SSRS even support this?

**Edit**

Converting the text to an expression and adding a double VbCrLf will not be feasible as I need to only add a partial line height

Answer (score 0):

You could add an expression on the Padding.Bottom property.

`=IIF(IncreaseHeight, "20pt", "2pt")`

Comment: What is "IncreaseHeight" ?? A function?

Answer (score 0):

If the text is already multiple lines, format the textbox to accept HTML.  Replace the line breaks with a white character in a larger font followed by a `<br/>` tag.

```
<span style=""font-size=12pt; color:white;"">|</span><br/>
```

If your text is all on the same line, do the above for each space in your text.  Using a bar "|" should be enough to represent the space between words.  If not, use a thicker character.

Comment: wow, necromantic post there :) I will give this a shot for the sake of the question but replace the pipe character with a no-break space `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late but hope it will help someone still looking for line-height in SSRS report.

Use SpaceAfter properties of textbox.

[image]